# How to force php to work in my browser?

Tags: php, cross-browser

I just installed PHP on my computer (Ubuntu). If I create a `test.php` file with simple code and then run "`php test.php`", it works fine (I get what I expect).

However, when I open this file (`test.php`) with my browser (Mozilla) it asks me how to open this file. Not a problem. I click "open with" and then I select "`/usr/bin/php`" and... nothing happens. Browser does not display anything.

Can anybody help me with that? Why does my browser cannot display a local php-file using a local php server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install a web server (apache, lighttpd, ngnix etc.) on your machine, then make sure the server is setup to process php files through the php interpreter. After you have done all that, copy the php files to your server web root directory and access them through the browser.

Comment: OK. I did everything except the last step. I do not know where is "my server web root directory".

Comment: Check (and understand) your http configuration file. In *nix it's usually in somewhere like /etc/apache2/httpd.conf (you could try locate httpd.conf to find it). You need a handler in there eg.

Answer (score 2):

XAMPP is probably the easiest way to get a development environment up and running.

[Here is forum article on getting it running on Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=223410).

Comment: I would not advice XAMPP. Just apache with the mod_php will do.

Comment: Ubuntu tasksel will pull all the correct packages and configure them to work together. It's kind of like XAMPP but plays nicely with the package manager. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a web server installed also?

This will install a full LAMP stack on Ubuntu.

`sudo tasksel install lamp-server`

But keep in mind this will launch Apache and MySQL daemons in the background.
To disable when you are not developing:
`sudo /etc/init.d/apache stop; sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

When you are:
`sudo /etc/init.d/apache start; sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

You can make a macro in your favorite IDE to do this automatically.

Removing it is as easy as:

`sudo tasksel remove lamp-server`

Answer (score 0):

Vertex

PHP through a browser will only work if you have php running as a webserver module (cgi, fcgi)

If you are on a regular linux distro you can probably apt-get emerge or zypper apache2 and the mod_php module from a repository. If you want to build from source, here is an small howto:
[apache2php](http://dan.drydog.com/apache2php.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on *nix, try

```
locate httpd.conf
```

to find the apache configuration file. It should be somewhere like /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.

In the httpd.conf file, you need to do two things. First load the PHP module eg.

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Then you also need a PHP file handler eg.

```
# PHP file handlers.
<IfModule php5_module>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

        <IfModule dir_module>
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

To test it's running OK, start apache with the .conf file as a parameter and load up a .php file that contains:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

If PHP is running ok under apache, you should see a purple/white/black page listing all the settings currently in use.

See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php for details of the myriad settings you can use.

Make sure you restart apache each and every time you change the .conf file!!!!